# How to remove Custom Properties from a SoapUI TestCase using Groovy?

Tags: groovy, properties, scripting, automation, soapui

I have created some list of properties under the TestCase. For example look at the following screenshot.

[image: SoapUI Pro - Testcase Properties]

I tried to remove **Testcase_Property** property through the following groovy script teststep:

```
testRunner.testCase.testSuite.removeProperty( "Testcase_Property" );
```

when I reload the project, the **Testcase_Property** property is still exist in the **Custom Properties** tab when I click on the Test case name.

Anyone suggest me what the correct script to remove the custom properties in SoapUI.

Thanks
Karunagara Pandi

Answer (score 6):

Finally I got the answers for removing Project, Testsuite and Testcase custom properties. Here are the scripts.

```
testRunner.testCase.testSuite.project.removeProperty( "Project_Level_Property" );
testRunner.testCase.testSuite.removeProperty( "Testsuite_Property" );
testRunner.testCase.removeProperty( "Testcase_Property" );
```

If any other way is there, please let me know friends.

Answer (score 6):

you can also use the following:

```
data = context.testCase.getTestStepByName("Test Case Name");

String[] propToRemove = new String[data.getPropertyCount()];
propToRemove = data.getPropertyNames();
for ( int i = 0 ; i < propToRemove.size(); i++ ){
    data.removeProperty( propToRemove[i] );
}
```

Hope this helps.
Now you can remove more than one prop.

Comment: It works, but you have a typo in last line. should be: data.removeProperty( propToRemove[i] );

Comment: adjusted the typo. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

**Manual solution**: use "Save Properties" and "Load Properties" from SoapUI

[image: SoapUI Save Properties button]

1. export the properties to a text file, e.g. `customprop.txt`
2. edit the file and delete the unwanted properties
3. import the file back into your soapUI project
4. in the "load properties" dialog check the option to "delete remaining"

Then the existing properties will be cleared out and replaced with your `customprop.txt`

Answer (score 0):

Just for completeness:

Another quick but **dirty and dangerous** way is to modify the `soapui-project.xml` and remove the property nodes with a text editor.
**Be aware that you can break your whole project if you do something wrong!**
You should create a copy of your `soapui-project.xml` and do the following steps:

1. Set the values of the Properties you want to delete to `deleteMe`
2. Search for the string `deleteMe` in your `soapui-project.xml`
3. Delete the properties:

`<con:property><con:name>name</con:name><con:value>deleteMe</con:value></con:property>`