# How to remove custome properties from SOAPUI test case using java?

Tags: java, soapui

I have some custom properties for all the test cases in SoapUI.

I am able to delete using Groovy script step as described in below question:

[How to remove Custom Properties from a SoapUI TestCase using Groovy?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25051709/how-to-remove-custom-properties-from-a-soapui-testcase-using-groovy)

```
testRunner.testCase.removeProperty( "Testcase_Property" );
```

But I wanted to delete these properties from JAVA. Below is the code I wrote:

```
    String soapuiProjectPath = "ProjectLocation";
    WsdlProject project = new WsdlProject(soapuiProjectPath);

    StringToObjectMap context = new StringToObjectMap();
    TestSuite testSuite = project.getTestSuiteByName("TestSuiteName");
    WsdlTestSuite wsdlSuite = (WsdlTestSuite) testSuite;

    List<TestCase> allTestCaseList = wsdlSuite.getTestCaseList();
    for (TestCase testCase : allTestCaseList) {
        WsdlTestCaseRunner testCaseRunner = new WsdlTestCaseRunner((WsdlTestCase) testCase, context);

        List<TestProperty> testCasePropertyList = testCase.getPropertyList();
        for (TestProperty testProperty : testCasePropertyList) {
        WsdlTestRunContext runContext = testCaseRunner.getRunContext();
        runContext.removeProperty(testProperty.getName());
        }
    }
    System.out.println("Completed execution.");
    project.save();
```

It is not throwing any exception. But not actually removing the custom properties as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because you've to apply the `removeProperty` in `WsdlTestCase` not in `WsdlTestRunContext`. You can change your *testCase* loop code for something like:

```
for(TestCase testCase : allTestCaseList) {
    List<TestProperty> testCasePropertyList = testCase.getPropertyList();
       for (TestProperty testProperty : testCasePropertyList) {
            ((WsdlTestCase) testCase).removeProperty(testProperty.getName());
        }
}
```

Hope it helps,

Comment: @HemaSundar nice to help you `:)`